# Swift 2 - UIPickerView values of two components

Tags: swift2, uipickerview, uipickerviewdelegate

I have a `UIPickerView` with two components, when I change `component[0] the data of the`component[1]` is reloaded.

Now I am trying to get the values of both components in one string using `didSelectRow` however, I cannot get the result I want.

```
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if component == 0 {

            String0 = arr0[row]
            pickerView.reloadComponent(1)

        }
        if component == 1{

        String1 = arr1[row]

        }

        print("\(String0), \(String1)")

        // result: " , string1.value"
    }
```

When I select `component[0]` the result changes but only for `String0`
What i am trying to achieve is to get `"string0.value, string1.value"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method `selectedRowInComponent` to get the selected row in each component, The selected row would be your correct index to form the string.

**Try:**

```
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if component == 0 {
        pickerView.reloadComponent(1)

    }
    String0 = arr0[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    String1 = arr1[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]

    print("\(String0), \(String1)")

    // result: " , string1.value"
}
```